# Is it possible to create virtual fs in browser for react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, indexeddb

Here's the idea:
I want to build some kind of CodeSandBox clone for my educational project.
Decided to go with new Pika CDN & ES Modules, since I don't need to support old browsers + tech seems very interesting.
So no bundling.
User will type something in Monaco editor (React project), it will be stored in IndexedDB via "BrowserFS". 
Then, within browser I want to read all this data and recreate it virtually with the same structure, so everything works, for example: "import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.js"" will still work.
Is it possible? 
I see there are browser FileSystem implementation made by Google, that would do this by allowing to create folders/files, but as I see it was abandoned...

For now, tried just importing stuff back from IndexedDB, but then I end up with file content, not imported component from that folder.